# My laptop turns ON when I close the lid

Tags: shutdown, lid

I have a really strange problem that my laptop turns on automatically when I close the lid after being shutdown. I use 20.04.1 LTS on DELL Latitude-7310.

Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: Check power management setting in BIOS. Please see if this help you https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-in/sln316788/how-to-enable-or-disable-the-power-on-lid-open-feature-on-your-newer-notebook?lang=en.  I also suggest asking about it on Dell support.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is most likely a hardware issue and not related to Ubuntu